# Is it possible to find whether the monitor supports HDR content from it's EDID information

Tags: c#, monitor, gamma, edid, gamut

I have the EDID hex string of Display (or Monitor) I want to check whether the monitor supports HDR, HLG or SDR content. Is it possible to find out this information from EDID string ?

I have gone through the EDID 1.3 format and could not find any specific block which provides info about HDR parameter.

Comment: is the display  you are testing with CTA-861.3 compliant? https://standards.globalspec.com/std/10037169/CTA-861.3

Comment: I am looking for generic solution, where any display could be connected to output port. The display  may or may not be CTA-861.3 complaint. But in case it is compliant with CTA-861.3 how can I retrieve the HDR info ?